# Java JTextPane not updating after original string is changed

Tags: java, string, jtextpane

```
String previousText = editorPane.getText();
        String compiledString = previousText + "<br>" + message;
        editorPane.setText(compiledString);
```

The above code does not work, it wont update my JTextPane, but if I modify the code and change it to:

```
String previousText = editorPane.getText();
        String compiledString = previousText + "<br>" + message;
        editorPane.setText(message);
```

it works perfectly fine! Am I doing something wrong and can't see it?

Comment: Post SSCCE to let us check

Comment: Have you tried : calling repaint(), check whether the setText is made in the EDT, if an error/exception is thrown ?